# Can't load images from "Documents" folder in iPhone/iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I have a part which is supposed to save an image into my phone's "Documents" folder and then access it. It saves fine, but the load methods don't really work. Here's my .m code:

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          @"photo.png" ];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        return image;
        studentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image]; //UIImageView property
    }

- (UIImage*)loadBarcode
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          @"barcode.png" ];
        NSLog(@"%@", path);
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        return image;
        barcode = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image]; // UIImageView property 
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadBarcode];
    [self loadImage];

}
```

The files are definitely there to access, the file paths are correct. But the UIImageViews I'm trying to assign them to come up blank. I'm running out of options. Do you guys have any suggestions as to what it might be?

Comment: When you go to the filepath manually and open the image, does it really have content?

Comment: You have methods with return type UIImage and you didn't use the return object from these methods. Also the last line in these methods will not be executed as you are returning before the last line.

Comment: return image statement should be at last after setting image to imageview in your code. And also no need of return statement as you are not taking while calling the function. Make that function as (void)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `loadImage` method, the problem is here:

```
return image;
studentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
```

You first use `return` statement which transfers the control and never assign it to the `UIImageView` control.

It should be something like:

```
studentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
return image;
```

One more point, if `studentImage` is connected through IB, `DON'T re-allocate it`. Instead use:

```
studentImage.image = image;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This helped me find the answer! I messed up with my properties pretty badly, this was affecting my code. Thank you so much for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed now, was an issue with my property names, but thank you for helping me clean up my code!